how can i create image map chart in imageCharts
I want to create an image map chart with dynamic data is there any provision for map creation
I did not find any cht type which can create maps for me. because I searched a lot but was not able to find a solution for map generation in imageCharts . Can you please help me with this?
thanks for your help in advance .

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
